# Appcache is not working in android apk build with phonegap build

Tags: android, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I am trying to use ***appcache*** in my android application based on phonegap and build with ***phonegap build***.

The problem i am facing is ***appcache*** *is not working in my android app* though it's ***working in chrome and firefox browser of android***.

My remote website's source can be found here :

[Remote website source](https://gist.github.com/mdsahib/5472123)

My Phonegap source is this:

```
<script>
  window.location="http://192.168.0.10";
</script>
```

Possible suggestion can be this :

[html5 offline solution](https://tmkmobile.wordpress.com/2012/03/04/html5-offline-solution/).

I did not try this as this was a problem in phonegap 2.3 and it's fixed in phonegap 2.5.

References :

1. [Community post](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/application_cache_on_android_using_build_phonegap_com)
2. [Turning On Appcache on Changelog](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/blob/2.5.0/changelog)

As i am using phonegap build and that currently use [phonegap 2.5](https://build.phonegap.com/blog/phonegap-2-5-support) i didn't try that issue.

Any query/suggestion/answer is highly appreciated.